# Differentiating std::chrono durations that have the same type and ratio?

Tags: c++, c++11, alias, c++-chrono

I am looking for a strongly typed solution for `std::chrono` durations. I have duration types that depend on a run-time only value. I use a factory-like class to convert between durations using the runtime value. For example :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

using dseconds = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using blee = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1,1>>;
using tick = std::chrono::duration<size_t, std::ratio<1,64>>;

struct converter {
    tick to_tick(dseconds s) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick>(s / runtime_ratio);
    }

    tick to_tick(blee b) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick>(b);
    }

private:
    double runtime_ratio = 0.5;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    converter c;
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(dseconds{1}).count());
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(blee{1}).count());
}
```

The example is available on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dRELeC).

Notice the conversion from seconds applies the ratio, unlike the conversion from blee. This doesn't compile since both `dseconds` and `blee` are really the same type.

```
<source>:13:10: error: 'tick converter::to_tick(blee) const' cannot be overloaded with 'tick converter::to_tick(dseconds) const'
     tick to_tick(blee b) const {
          ^~~~~~~

<source>:9:10: note: previous declaration 'tick converter::to_tick(dseconds) const'
     tick to_tick(dseconds s) const {
          ^~~~~~~
```

I've tried using templated aliases to differentiate blee, but that didn't work. I've tried nesting aliases in other namespaces or structs, that didn't work either. I read [fluentc++](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/26/strong-types-conversions/)'s post about something similar, but I don't understand it and the api is really ugly and intrusive.

Is there a way to strongly type 2 duration alias with the same type and ratio?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but isn't this what inheritance is for?

Comment: I fail to see where inheritance comes into play here. std::chrono is compile time only, so no inheritance. My issue is with the type system being too smart and figuring out the aliases are really the same templated type. Feel free to expand on what you mean though.

Comment: Blee and dseconds are exactly the same type. To distinguish which function must be called, consider tag-dispatching.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Yep. Do you think that would be cleaner than the answer I posted? I'm kinda liking std::ratio<2,2> :)

Comment: It depends ... If it's buried somewhere in some template meta-programming, then tag-dispatching, otherwise why not use appropriately differently named functions?

Comment: I prefer the same functions name to have a simpler/cleaner api. Thx for the help!

Comment: @scx _"std::chrono is compile time only, so no inheritance"_ Sorry, that phrase makes no sense. Types are compile-time. Inheritance is compile-time. If you couldn't do inheritance on types because types are compile-time then there would be no inheritance at all, but I'm sure you know already that C++ has inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll suggest it again: *use inheritance*.

Right now your problem is the use of type aliases via `using`. This does not create new types, only new names for old types. You're trying to overload twice with the same type, which is meaningless and impossible as overloading does not care about the new names.

But *inheritance creates types*. That is its job; that is its purpose.

With this you can easily make what is sometimes called a "strong typedef" — a fresh, distinct type that otherwise behaves pretty much exactly like the thing you're deriving.

It does require a small amount of gymnastics, but the end result is pretty sexy, and could be trivially improved with another half hour's work. (For example, a little move semantics in that up-converting ctor probably wouldn't hurt…).

Here we go:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

using dseconds = std::chrono::duration<double>;

struct blee : std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1,1>>
{
    using DurationType = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1,1>>;
    using DurationType::DurationType;
    blee(const DurationType& other) : DurationType(other) {}
};

struct tick : std::chrono::duration<size_t, std::ratio<1,64>>
{
    using DurationType = std::chrono::duration<size_t, std::ratio<1,64>>;
    using DurationType::DurationType;
    tick(const DurationType& other) : DurationType(other) {}
};

struct converter {
    tick to_tick(dseconds s) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick::DurationType>(s / runtime_ratio);
    }

    tick to_tick(blee b) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick::DurationType>(b);
    }

private:
    double runtime_ratio = 0.5;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    converter c;
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(dseconds{1}).count());
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(blee{1}).count());
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10934b58f8d15120))

So, okay, you have to spend a few lines setting up the types. And, okay, you have to expand the `duration_cast` call a little.

But honestly that seems like a small price to pay to get a solution that does not rely on hackery!

*(In fact, you only really need to apply this to `blee`, but I did it to both for symmetry. Whether this is better or worse than leaving `tick` as a simple type alias is up to the reader.)*

I'd actually go so far as to say that this is the only semantically "correct" solution, because you really are creating semantically new types, and that is not what an alias is for. An alias is for making a convenient alternative name to some existing type.

Comment: I see what you mean by inheritance now, thanks for explaining your point. It seems like a better solution to me. On whether or not aliases are "correct", well you'll have to take it up to the c++ standard committee since that is how they intend one to use std::chrono ;) Good day

Comment: Implementing your solution works for the example, but it unfortunately breaks once you get into more complex scenarios (my solution breaks as well). Will probably follow-up the question with a more beefy use-case.

Comment: @scx I'm not sure I've seen anywhere that the committee "intend" people to use type aliases over inheritance when inheritance suits the problem better. That's generally not their remit. The language provides tools, and it is up to us to use those tools as best we can.

Comment: Would be interested to hear when the approach breaks - I can imagine some conversion issues in really complex code but then I'd probably try to de-complexify that code.

Answer (score 2):

OK well I've figured out some sort of hack. If you use `std::ratio<2,2>`, which is equivalent to `std::ratio<1,1>` anyways, the compiler stops complaining and treats both `dseconds` and `blee` as different types.

I will keep the question open if anyone has a better solution.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

using dseconds = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using blee = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<2,2>>;
using tick = std::chrono::duration<size_t, std::ratio<1,64>>;

struct converter {
    tick to_tick(dseconds s) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick>(s / runtime_ratio);
    }

    tick to_tick(blee b) const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<tick>(b);
    }

private:
    double runtime_ratio = 0.5;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    converter c;
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(dseconds{1}).count());
    printf("%zu", c.to_tick(blee{1}).count());
}
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nEdZfz)

Comment: This is as good as any other solution I can think of.  I note that there was a [proposal](https://wg21.link/p0656) about a year ago that would break this technique.  But as far as I can tell, this proposal has not advanced.

Comment: Is anything wrong with [`boost::strong_typedef`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp)?

Comment: @MooingDuck That's quite nice. Needs a bit of updating perhaps. A modern version of that could end up looking similar to an "evolved"/production-ready version of my suggestion.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Think we could probably do without the stereotyping here thanks. An owner of a law firm should surely know better...

Comment: Fair enough, that was more a bit of Saturday humor than stereotype. Point taken.